# how to differentiate Request from internet or intranet

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

i have a web application in that i need to differentiate both intranet and internet requests
how can i achieve this?

right now i have thought of using IP address to differentiate but there might be a chance of same intranet ip address for different organizations.

is there any effective way to differentiate

Thank you in advance

Comment: I take it that the site is hosted externally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use IP address. If people from other organisations are querying the page, they do it with their public IP address which is different from their intranet IP.

Only people from your intranet can ask with local IP addresses.