# Login with local access with ip

Tags: java, tomcat6

For an assigment I have a server with Tomcat 6. On this server we made a website where you can  log in. The problem is that we don't to log in on the website if you work local and we don't know how to do that.

We've tried to google on it and we found to use "x-forwarded-for", but that doesn't work. Then  you don't need to log in at all (extern too).

I hope you guys can help me!

Comment: What server side framework are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728909/how-to-differentiate-request-from-internet-or-intranet

Comment: We're running Java and Tomcat on an Ubuntu server, not a specific framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the request which is a `ServletRequest` instance (you might have to cast it) and call `getRemoteAddr()` on it.

JavaDoc on that method:

> Returns the Internet Protocol (IP) address of the client or last proxy that sent the request.

Locally you should get the ip 127.0.0.1. Additionally you might also want to check whether the request ip is the server's local ip.